# Не выполняется команда по настройке webpack

Tags: webpack

Установил вэбпак локально `npm install webpack --dev`
Вот мой package

```js
{
  "name": "webpack-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при воде npm run build происходит ошибка как быть?

Comment: какая ошибка -то?)

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil, добавил картинку из консоли

Comment: файл webpack.config.js есть у вас?

Comment: Да, там вот это `module.exports = {
 entry: './src/app.js',
 output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: './dist'
 }
}`

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS укажи абсолютный путь для папки dist и всё, сам вебпак говорит об этом )

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil Как в моём случае это написать и куда?

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS импортируешь функцию из node.js
var path = require('path')
и прокидываешь в output.path: 
path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist')